# jQuery - Select same elements and move them into their own parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each, appendto

I'm currently working on a website based on WordPress. I would like to use jQuery to move the date of blog posts. I can not edit the template because it is used on other pages.

Precisely, I would like to move the .entry-time element under .entry-title

Here's is the HTML code:

```
<div class="post-content-container">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Blog 1</h2>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <p class="entry-meta-details">
            <span class="entry-time">
                <span class="updated" style="display:none;">2014-06-24T13:58:52+00:00</span>
                <time class="published">June 24th, 2014</time>
            </span>
        </p>
</div>
<div class="post-content-container">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Blog 2</h2>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <p class="entry-meta-details">
            <span class="entry-time">
                <span class="updated" style="display:none;">2014-06-20T13:58:52+00:00</span>
                <time class="published">June 20th, 2014</time>
            </span>
        </p>
</div>
<div class="post-content-container">
    <h2 class="entry-title">Blog 3</h2>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <p class="entry-meta-details">
            <span class="entry-time">
                <span class="updated" style="display:none;">2014-05-20T13:58:52+00:00</span>
                <time class="published">May 20th, 2014</time>
            </span>
        </p>
</div>
```

And here is what I've done so far using jQuery:

```
jQuery(".post-content-container").find(".entry-time").each(function(){
            jQuery(this).appendTo(".entry-title");
    });
```

The element ".entry-time" is in the right place but there is something wrong with my loop. The three dates are displayed under each blog title:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCA8G.png

Could you help me to fix the loop?

Thanks,
Damien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your selector in `.appendTo(".entry-title")` matches all three entry titles each time. What you want is to match only the relevant title for each specific `.entry-time`. To do that, one way is to navigate the DOM to the correct target, e.g. one way is:

```
jQuery(".post-content-container").find(".entry-time").each(function(){
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.appendTo($this.closest(".post-content-container").find(".entry-title"));
});
```

Of course when you look at it afterwards it invites pulling the `.each` up so as to not have to traverse the DOM multiple times for the same element:

```
jQuery(".post-content-container").each(function() {
    var $this = jQuery(this);
    $this.find(".entry-time").appendTo($this.find(".entry-title"));
});
```

And I really like this evolved version much better: the body of the callback reads very close to natural language.

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly! I've never used "$this.find" before but I can see the point now. Cheers!

Comment: @DamienMorvan: Glad to help, I just "cache" `jQuery(this)` because 99% of the time you need it more than once.

Answer (score 0):

You're not selecting the specific `.entry-title` corresponding to the current item.

```
jQuery(".post-content-container").find(".entry-time").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).appendTo($(this).closest(".entry-meta").prev(".entry-title"));
});
```